# Embed Tweet in Drupal 7 Blog in [tweet] format

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am creating a Drupal 7 blog to replace a WordPress blog. I am done with it and imported all the wordpress blogs, but didn't realize the client had an embedded tweet feature from wordpress. It's in the format of

[Tweet "QUOTE HERE"]

and it formats it nicely embedded in their blog (on wordpress). Anyone know of a way to have this same functionality in Drupal? When the user clicks it, they can tweet that quote from the blog/article.

Comment: do you want hashtag tweets or what? you can create a hashtag search app in twitter

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki no. It's a function where the user posting a blog/article can predetermine their favorite or most newsworthy sentence and then "feature" it so users can click the box to tweet that sentence. It's not embedding something that's already on twitter or using hashtags. See www.govevents.com/blog for an example of this in action.

Comment: check this link out https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/parameters#button and see section Web Intent example shown at bottom of page

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki this won't really work for the non-tech blog users of this website, they need a GUI where they can just highlight a sentence, it puts it in the tweet box with a link back to their blog post when it's posted on twitter. These people don't really understand HTML/etc unfortunately. Also I was hoping to find something that  might work with their 400 existing blogs that I imported, where now it just has plain text in the blog that says [Tweet "quote "] anywhere they do that.

Comment: For this you have to write js or php code so that you can replace "[Tweet "quote "]" with the exact link which will work with twitter. using php will be better to replace the text "[Tweet "quote "]" in your content

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki I don't think I know enough code to modify Drupals core blog module to do this. I know modifying/hacking the core can cause problems when we update. I need something permanent and I'm not sure how. If I edit their blog interface to have a function for this, won't it just disappear when we update?

Comment: Never hack the core. I will suggest you to use hook_block_view_alter hook to do the stuff you need in your custom module. Here you will get the block content and you can change it as you need.